# PHP: Placing the label of a Zend Form Element Text to the right of the element

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm doing a project for uni, and as a part of it I am translating some of the pages, and need them in RTL.

These text fields are declared in a class on a different file.

I've managed to set the calling page to RTL (using `[html dir='rtl']`), which moved all the elements to the right of the page, but the labels of the text elements are to their left, and aligned to the left of the page.

Using `[html dir='rtl']` in this file had no effect.

These are the relevant parts of the code (I think):

```
$keywords = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('keywords' , array('size' => '30'));
$keywords->setLabel('Keywords from Abstract')
->addFilter('StripTags')
->addFilter('StringTrim')
->setDescription('Enter one or more keywords, separated by whitespace.')
;

// Definition of additional (almost identical) elements

$this->addElements(array(..., $keywords , ... ));

$this->setDecorators(array(
'FormElements',    
array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'search')),
array('Description', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
'Form'
));
```

How can i move the labels to the right of the text elements?

Note that I've tried changing the last line to say 'placement' => 'append' , which did not seem to change anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change position of `label` decorator this way:

```
$decorator = $keywords->getDecorator('Label');
if ($decorator) $decorator->setOption('placement', Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND);
```

Than change styles for proper form output:

```
form dd {display: inline-block; width: 60%;}
form dt {display: inline-block; width: 35%;}
```

Comment: I've tried to change the label placement as you said, but it just puts the label below the text box (and still aligned to the left).
Also I'm not sure about the last two lines you added. Where do I place them?

Comment: last 2 lines are styles, place them in styles as is or in html as `<style>form dd {display: inline-block; width: 60%;}
form dt {display: inline-block; width: 35%;}</style>`